# Pine Script object reference error. Pass by value or reference?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I don't understand what pine script v5 is doing here.
In a simple example I have a matrix object. This object gets referenced by a variable. At least I'd expect it gets referenced and not just receives the value... but no other reference is possible, so I don't know. However, `var` somehow manages to receive and keep the state change of the object until the very last bar, but it seems to be hanging on the variable declaration.
So is it pass by reference or pass by value or "pass by pine script"?
Any thoughts highly appreciated.

```
//@version=5
library("testlib")

// No global initialization is possible in library
getFoo() => var matrix<float> foo = matrix.new<float>()


export testReference() =>
    // init foo on the 1st bar with "var" and work with the reference afterwards
    matrix<float> f = getFoo()
    
    // random matrix logic on the timeline
    if dayofmonth == 20 and month == 8 and year == 2022
        matrix.add_row(f, matrix.rows(f))
        label.new(bar_index, high, 'rows +' + str.tostring(matrix.rows(f))) // works as expected: rows + 1
        
    if barstate.islast
        label.new(bar_index, high, 'rows: ' + str.tostring(matrix.rows(f)), color=color.green) // works as expected: rows == 1
        
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        label.new(bar_index + 3, high, 'rows: ' + str.tostring(matrix.rows(getFoo())), color=color.red) // reference not working
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////
// call from a script
testReference()

plot(close)
```

----------------------------
**Update:**
----------------------------
After contacting the pine support they assured me it is supposed to work like this and it's not a bug. Unfortunately no further explanation. "I should read the [docs](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#var)". Of course there is no mention about this behavior there. This [thread](https://www.tradingview.com/script/f9Yrc0LO-Explaining-VAR/) stands the closest to the issue and the solution/reason behind this. It's disappointing there is no official statement about it anywhere.
It's still somewhat a mystery to me how this really works.

Answer (score 0):

The functions in pinescipt returns a variable by value, not by reference.

So on line `matrix<float> f = getFoo()` you copy the value of `foo` to `f`. On the lines `str.tostring(matrix.rows(f)` you just working with the `f` variables, the `foo` variable does not get effected.

Then when you run `str.tostring(matrix.rows(getFoo()))` you get a new copy of the values in `foo`

Some code that illustrated that it is a copy.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

getFoo() => 
    var int a = 0
    a+=1 //reference to a is working. Every bar a gets larger
    a

b = getFoo() //b is just a copy of a 
b+=100 //test comment this line. if line is NOT commented the value of b is 766 for me. If commented the value is 666.
plotchar(b, "b", "", location = location.top)
```

[image: b tradingview value image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I'm with you on that! Your example is working perfectly with integers. However try your theory with matrix instead. Change your code a bit: getFoo() => var matrix<float> a = matrix.new<float>() \n b = getFoo() \n matrix.add_row(b, matrix.rows(b)) // END. So what's happening here? I copy my matrix to b and manipulate b. If I assign the copy to a variable and I manipulate that variable (which is not a reference), am I allowed to and capable of updating the base "a"? Definitely NOT. What is working perfectly with int in your example fails totally with matrix.